# How to defer multiple ajax success callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, synchronization

In my Javascript, I have the following scenario:

```
call_A(success_A)

call_B(success_B)


function call_A(success){
// make ajax request
success(result)
}

function call_B(success){
//make ajax request
success(result)
}


function success_A(){
  //set data to be used by success_B
}

function success_B(){
..do some stuff
}
```

I want to make both `call_A` and `call_B` one after the other so that ajax calls are made (to save time).

I do not have the option for changing `call_A` and `call_B` function headers, so the call to these function has to be made specifying the success callback function.

What I want is that regardless of which of the 2 ajax call finishes first, I want `success_A` get called before `success_B`, because B depends on A's data.

What is the best way of getting this done?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It has the $.Deferred class which adds a lot of syntax sugar for cases like this.

Comment: Also, you should probably rewrite your example code to be in JavaScript. def is not the way to define javascript functions so it makes your question a little confusing IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
a_success= false;
b_success= false;

call_A(generalSuccess);
call_B(generalSuccess);

function call_A(success) {
    // make ajax request
    a_success = true;
    success(result)
}

function call_B(success) {
    //make ajax request
    b_success = true;
    success(result)
}

function generalSuccess() {
    //assuming you are passing which a or b is called. set b_success or a_success is true
    if (a_success == true && b_success == true) {
        // use all variables you need and get the final result
    } else if (a_success == true) {
        // set your desired value into a global variable from a request
    } else if (b_success == true) {
        // set results to use from b request.
    }
}
```